# In Asterisk, is there an AMI action for forcing a phone to answer an incoming call?

Tags: asterisk

I'm running Asterisk v1.8.6.0.

I'm trying to figure out the correct Manager/AMI action or command to use when an incoming call is coming in, to pick it up. If extension 100 calls in, and they are put on hold, how could I send that call to another extension?

If ext 100 is on hold, I'd like to be able to run an AMI action or command to have ext 101's phone ring, and when he picks up, he's connected to ext 100.

Comment: Do you have a usage scenario for this?  It's probably all possible but I'm not sure why you'd want this or if there'd be a better way to do it.